# Understanding streamlit data flow and how to submit form in a sequential way

Tags: python, streamlit

Below is a simple reproducible example that works to illustrate the problem in its simple form. You can jump to the code and expected behaviour as the problem description can be long.

### The main concept

There are 3 dataframes stored in a list, and a form on the sidebar shows the `supplier_name` and `po_number` from the relevant dataframe. When the user clicks the `Next` button, the information inside the `supplier_name` and `po_number` **text_input** will be saved (in this example, they basically got printed out on top of the sidebar).
[image]

### Problem

This app works well when the user don't change anything inside the **text_input**, but if the user changes something, it breaks the app. See below pic for example, when I change the `po_number` to `somethingrandom`, the saved information is not `somethingrandom` but `p123` from the first dataframe.

[image]

What's more, if the information from the next dataframe is the same as the first dataframe, the changed value inside the text_input will be unchanged for the next display. For example, because the first and second dataframe's supplier name are both `S1`, if I change the supplier name to `S10`, then click next, the `supplier_name` is still `S10` on the second dataframe, while the second dataframe's supplier_name should be `S1`. But if the supplier name for the next dataframe changed, the information inside the `text_input` will be changed.

### Justification

If you are struggling to understand why I want to do this, the original use for this is for the sidebar input area to extract information from each PDFs, then when the user confirms the information are all correct, they click next to review the next PDF. But if something is wrong, they can change the information inside the text_input, then click next, and the information of the changed value will be recorded, and for the next pdf, the extracted information should reflect on what the next pdf is. I did this in R shiny quite simply, but can't figure out how the data flow works here in streamlit, please help.

### Reproducible Example

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# 3 dataframes that are stored in a list
data1 = {
    "supplier_name": ["S1"],
    "po_number": ["P123"],
}
data2 = {
    "supplier_name": ["S1"],
    "po_number": ["P124"],
}
data3 = {
    "supplier_name": ["S2"],
    "po_number": ["P125"],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

list1 = [df1, df2, df3]

# initiate a page session state, every time next button is clicked
# it will go to the next dataframe in the list
if 'page' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.page = 0

def next_page():
    st.sidebar.write(f"Submitted! supplier_name: {supplier_name} po_number: {po_number}")
    st.session_state.page += 1

supplier_name_value = list1[st.session_state.page]["supplier_name"][0]
po_number_value = list1[st.session_state.page]["po_number"][0]

# main area
list1[st.session_state.page]

# sidebar form

with st.sidebar.form("form"):
   supplier_name = st.text_input(label="Supplier Name", value=supplier_name_value)
   po_number = st.text_input(label="PO Number", value=po_number_value)
   next_button = st.form_submit_button("Next", on_click=next_page)
```

### Expected behaviour

The dataframe's info are extracted into the sidebar input area. The user can change the input if they wish, then click next, and the values inside the input areas will be saved. When it goes to the next dataframe, the values inside the text input will be refreshed to extract from the next dataframe, and repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're going for, but after some messing around, the only way I was able to achieve this sort of sequential form submission handling is with [`st.experimental_rerun()`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.experimental_rerun). I hate to resort to that since it may be removed any time, so hopefully there's a better way.

Without `experimental_rerun()`, forms take two submits to actually update state. I wasn't able to find a "correct" way to achieve an immediate update to support the expected behavior.

Here's my attempt:

```py
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1
import streamlit as st  # 1.18.1


def initialize_state():
    data = [
        {
            "supplier_name": ["S1"],
            "po_number": ["P123"],
        },
        {
            "supplier_name": ["S1"],
            "po_number": ["P124"],
        },
        {
            "supplier_name": ["S2"],
            "po_number": ["P125"],
        },
    ]
    state.dfs = state.get("dfs", [pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data])
    first_vals = [{x: df[x][0] for x in df.columns} for df in state.dfs]
    state.selections = state.get("selections", first_vals)
    state.pages_expanded = state.get("pages_expanded", 0)
    state.current_page = state.get("current_page", 0)
    state.just_modified_page = state.get("just_modified_page", -1)


def handle_submit(i):
    st.session_state.selections[i] = {
        "supplier_name": state.new_supplier_name,
        "po_number": state.new_po_number,
    }
    state.current_page = i
    state.just_modified_page = i

    if i < len(state.dfs) - 1 and state.pages_expanded == i:
        state.pages_expanded += 1

    st.experimental_rerun()


def render_form(i):
    with st.sidebar.form(key=f"form-{i}"):
        supplier_name = state.selections[i]["supplier_name"]
        po_number = state.selections[i]["po_number"]

        if i == state.just_modified_page:
            st.sidebar.write(
                f"Submitted! supplier_name: {supplier_name} "
                f"po_number: {po_number}"
            )
            state.just_modified_page = -1

        state.new_supplier_name = st.text_input(
            label="Supplier Name",
            value=supplier_name,
        )
        state.new_po_number = st.text_input(
            label="PO Number",
            value=po_number,
        )

        if st.form_submit_button("Next"):
            handle_submit(i)


state = st.session_state
initialize_state()

for i in range(state.pages_expanded + 1):
    render_form(i)

# debug
st.write("state.pages_expanded", state.pages_expanded)
st.write("state.current_page", state.current_page)
st.write("state.just_modified_page", state.just_modified_page)
st.write("state.dfs[state.current_page]", state.dfs[state.current_page])
st.write("state.selections", state.selections)
```

I'm assuming you want to keep track of the user's selections, but not actually modify the dataframes. If you do want to modify the dataframes, that's simpler: replace `state.selections` with actual writes to `dfs` by index and column:

```py
# ...
def handle_submit(i):
    st.session_state.dfs[i]["supplier_name"] = state.new_supplier_name,
    st.session_state.dfs[i]["po_number"] = state.new_po_number,
    #st.session_state.selections[i] = {
    #    "supplier_name": state.new_supplier_name,
    #    "po_number": state.new_po_number,
    #}

# ...

def render_form(i):
    with st.sidebar.form(key=f"form-{i}"):
        supplier_name = state.dfs[i]["supplier_name"][0]
        po_number = state.dfs[i]["po_number"][0]
        #supplier_name = state.selections[i]["supplier_name"]
        #po_number = state.selections[i]["po_number"]
# ...
```

Now, it's possible to make this 100% dynamic, but I hardcoded `supplier_name` and `po_number` to avoid premature generalization that you may not need. If you do want to generalize, use `df.columns` like `initialize_state` does throughout the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the experiment_run as well days ago and you are right, it's a feature that could be potentially removed. And I'm quite confused on why it needs to click the button twice to extract the info, as the app didn't get refreshed from top to bottom when the button is clicked. One way to bypass experiemnt_run is to use on_click then assign key to widgets, I haven't tried it yet, will update here later.

Comment: The goal is basically to first read a batch of documents, and all of those documents (imagine each document is a dataframe) are stored in a list. Then sidebar reads what's inside each document one by one, but if something looks wrong, user can correct the sidebar. After user clicks next, those info will be saved into an excel spreadsheet, and user will go to the next document in the list. The actual document won't get amended, but those info will be saved. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using `on_click` handlers but wasn't able to get it working, which is why I resorted to `experimental_rerun()`. I'd also like to revisit this when I can and try to get it working with callbacks, but feel free to leave a comment and an answer if you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems like you're never updating the supplier name in `list1` after the user updates the name via the text input widget.